# php and mysql search code not work (please view code and debug)

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I create `search.php` and create database `war` and table `product`.

My code doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>متن برای جستجو</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Search"></td>
                <td>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_GET['text']) && !empty($_GET['text'])){
                        $body=$_GET['text'];
                        $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                        if(!$con){die("mysql Error");}
                        if (!mysql_select_db("war",$con)){die("mysql select error");}
                        $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE LIKE pname='%$body%'");
                        $count=mysql_num_rows($res);
                        if ($count <= 0){
                            die("Your product Not found");

                        }else{
                            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                                echo $row['pname'];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help and debug.

Comment: How can we "help and debug" without the full code?

Comment: <?php
if(isset($_GET['text']) && !empty($_GET['text'])){
        $body=$_GET['text'];
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
          if(!$con){die("mysql Error");}
          if (!mysql_select_db("war",$con)){die("mysql select error");}
          $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE LIKE pname='%$body%'");
          $count=mysql_num_rows($res);
          if ($count <= 0){
           die("Your product Not found");
          }else{
           while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            echo $row['pname'];
           }
          }
         }
        ?>

Comment: _'doesn't work'_ is not a problem description

Comment: StackOverflow is a question and answer site, not a site for posting "plz fix my codez" requests disguised as a question. [**http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/**](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MySQL` SELECT statement is wrong. It should be:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE pname LIKE '%$body%'"); // note the absence of =
```

If this is, of course, what you mean by "*it doesn't work*".

PS : do **not** use `mysql_*` functions. [They are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).